# About $e^{i \theta}$ and mapping complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis

So, $e^{i \theta}$ is a unit circle centered at the origin, and $e^{i\theta}-1$ is a unit circle centered at $-1$. If we have a complex function $M_a(z) = \frac{z-a}{\overline{a}z-1},$ I am required to show that this maps a unit circle to itself. So I tried to visualize this using mathematica and found these two figures : [image: figure]

So the first figure shows the input $z$ and the second one shows the image $M_a(z)$. I clearly can see that this function maps a unit circle to itself, but $M_a(z)$ start at $270^{\circ}$ and go clock-wise. why is this happening?? And how can I show this result??

One another question is how can I interpret $\frac{1}{e^{i\theta}}$ geometrically?? So $e^{i\theta}$ is a unit circle, then what is the fraction of it?? Thank you!

Comment: Consider that $\dfrac{1}{e^{i\theta}} = e^{-i\theta} = \overline{e^{i\theta}}$. You can view it as a complex conjugate or a rotation in the opposite (clockwise) direction.

Comment: @Brad Oh, that was simple. Thanks. So what about $\frac{1}{e^{i \theta} -1}$?? Is it conjugate of a unit circle centered at -1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{1}{e^{i\theta}}={e^{-i\theta}}\text{, i.e., a rotation in the opposite direction.}\\
\dfrac{1}{e^{i\theta}-1}\text{ about the origin is }\left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}e^{i(\theta k+\pi)}\right)\\
\text{This is a sum (as $k$ increases) of rotations by angle $\theta k+\pi$ about the origin.}\\
\text{Of course, there are many other interpretations, and this is mine.}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. Can you give me more detail?? I dont follow how u got $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{i (\theta k + \pi)}$ from $\frac{1}{e^{i\theta}-1}.$

Comment: @eChung00 Use the Taylor series expansion of $\dfrac{1}{x-1}$ about the origin. Then, use $e^{i\pi}=-1$ - Euler's formula.